# How can I use GetAllUsers in the ASP Membership provider?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, membership-provider

I am trying to make a list of all the users of my system and using the following:

```
    public MembershipUserCollection GetAllUsers(int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
    {
        return _provider.GetAllUsers(pageIndex, pageSize, out totalRecords);
    }
```

But I don't understand how to use these parameters. I have looked around on the web and can't find any examples.

Does anyone have an example of where they have C# code to query and list users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method supports paging. If your userbase is small or you don't care about paging, you could simply use another [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy8swhya.aspx) that doesn't expect any parameters.

```
public static MembershipUserCollection GetAllUsers()
```